# do some statement under a condition without using a single if

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to solve flowing problem:

You are given an integer called n.
print '+' if n is positive,
print '-' if n is negative,
print '0' if n is zero.

write a c\c++ solution without using a single if!

I wrote this code:

```
int n;
scanf("%d", &n);

! n >> (sizeof(n) - 1) && printf("-") || return 0;
n > 0 && prtintf("+") || return 0;
printf("0");
retuen 0;
```

but i get error: expected primary-expression before 'return' for line 3 and 4.
how can I change this code to make it work!

p.s: using ? : operator is considered cheating!

Comment: Try this `return (n > 0 ? '+' : (n < 0 ? '-' : '0'))`

Comment: Use the ternary conditional operator: `<condition>?<true_val>:<false_val>`

Comment: The code you posted is incoherent, to say the least. In ordert to "fix" this code you first would have to explain how you intended it to work. It is completely unclear from what you posted.

Comment: What's `! n >> (sizeof(n) - 1)` supposed to do?

Comment: the last bit of integer n is the sign of the number : 0 for zero and positive and 1 for negative. google two's complement

Comment: What language are you coming from? This is highly un-idiomatic C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is doable (with some restrictions).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

// Assuming 2s-complement numbers
// and an understanding compiler
// Some checks omitted!

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int input;
  unsigned int itmp;
  int size;
  int sign, sin, sout;
  char out[3] = { '0', '+', '-' };


  if (argc != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s integer\n", argv[0]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  // TODO: use strtol and check input!
  input = atoi(argv[1]);

  size = sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT;
  itmp = (unsigned int) input;

  sin = itmp >> (size - 1);
  sign = sin ^ 1;

  // now "sign" is either 0 (negative) or 1 (positive)
  // but we need 1 (negative) and -1 (positive)
  // 0 * -2 + 1 = 1
  // 1 * -2 + 1 = -1

  sign = sign * -2 + 1;

  // Now we can do
  // in   sign   out   sin   sout
  // -x *   1 = -x ->   1  +  1  =  2
  // +x *  -1 = -x ->   0  +  1  =  1
  //  0 *  -1 =  0 ->   0  +  0  =  0

  itmp = itmp * sign;
  sout = itmp >> (size - 1);

  sign = sin + sout;

  printf("Input: %c\n", out[(size_t) sign]);

  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

No conditional expressions, neither explicit with `if`, nor implicit with `while` or `for`, nor the shortcut `...?...:...`.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional operator `?:` is the simplest and the most appropriate answer here.

But if you wish, you can do

```
int n = -5;
...
const char s[] = { '-', '0', '+' };
std::cout << (s + 1)[(n > 0) - (n < 0)] << std::endl;
```

If I correctly deciphered the intent of your original code, the solution based on the short-circuiting properties of logocal operators might look as follows

```
 (n < 0 && (std::cout << '-', true)) || 
   (n > 0 && (std::cout << '+', true)) || 
   (std::cout << '0', true);
 std::cout << std::endl;
```

Don't try to inject `return` statements into expressions. `return` is a statement, not an operator. You cannot use `return` in an expression.

Comment: but i can use exit(code) in order to terminate the program. what about i would like to terminate a function?

Comment: @user3073850: Firstly, `exit` does not terminate a function. It terminates the entire program. Secondly, where did "terminate a function" come from? Your original post says nothing about any "functions" or "terminations".

Comment: corrected the question sorry

Comment: @user3073850: If I'm not missing anything, the only way to "terminate a function" from inside an expression is probably `throw`. And `throw` does not exactly "terminate a function". You can also use `switch` instead of `if` here, and then freely use `return` inside `switch`, but I'm afraid it would also be "considered cheating".